# How to get the date(incl. day-name like Monday, July 06...) in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one please tell me how to get the day in .net.
I know how to get date as **6/7/2015**.But instead i need to get **Monday,July 6.**..

Comment: Real lack of research here...

Comment: Can you please show complete string that you want as a result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.ToLongDateString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();  // Monday, July 06, 2015
```

From MSDN:

> The string returned by the ToLongDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard long date pattern is "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"; for
>   the de-DE culture, it is "dddd, d. MMMM yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture,
>   it is "yyyy'?'M'?'d'?'". The specific format string on a particular
>   computer can also be customized so that it differs from the standard
>   long date format string.

So this method uses the current culture to determine the `LongDatePattern` and language, you can use this approach if you want to specify a different culture yourself:

```
var deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // germany
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString(deCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, deCulture);
// Montag, 6. Juli 2015
var jaCulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP"); // japain
date = DateTime.Today.ToString(jaCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, jaCulture);  
// 2015年7月6日
```

If you want to build a custom format pattern: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: +1 ...  or just supply your own custom date pattern, e.g. `var date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd, dd-MM-yyyy")` the "dddd" portion specifies name of the day.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: yes, i've added the link to MSDN where it is explained all.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dt = DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
lblcurrentdate.Text = dt;
```